# Monodevelop "Portable Library" project References are not available

Tags: c#, monodevelop, portability

Greetings,

Recently i come cross a problem while developing a cross platform project.
In this project, I have to support android, ios, and wp7, what I did is to create 3 projects for these 3 platforms, and I have another project which can be shared among the 3 target platform.

So I created this project as a "Portable Library", and add reference to this project in the other projects. It worked, I can use Class defined in this shared project in the other 3 projects, but the problem is, in the portable library project, the "References" folder, "System", "System.Core", and "System.Xml" are red, when I unfold it, it says "assembly not available for .NETPortable 4.0 Profile1 Profile (in Mono 2.10.9)". I googled this piece of information, but none gave me the satisfying answer.

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/cross-platform-library-code-td4656600.html

So, how can fix it? What are these "System", "System.Xml", "System.Core" for? Are they files? Or within a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the references being red for now. That just indicates that you don't have the PCL assemblies on your system (which you won't have unless you are on Windows), however Xamarin is working on generating PCL assemblies and hopes to have them "soon" (by May?).

In the meantime, this is "ok" because when you are targeting Mono for Android or MonoTouch on Mac OS X w/ MonoDevelop, what MonoDevelop does is link with the Mono for Android or MonoTouch frameworks instead, which is good enough for what you want do to.

Things to consider:

1. You won't be able to share the assembly with your WP7 app (because the assembly built by MonoDevelop won't be a true PCL assembly), but you'll be able to share the Portable Library *project* - i.e. just make sure to do a fresh build of the project for each platform. (you can share between MonoTouch and Mono for Android, but not with WP7)
2. Since the referenced assemblies are red, as you've noticed, it means that MonoDevelop won't be able to do proper code-completion. If you're a Windows guy, you could just develop the Portable Library in Visual Studio and then just share it with your iOS and Android projects. Once Mono has real PCL assemblies, this problem will go away.
3. There are some bugs in the current public releases of MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio where it doesn't like certain profiles. Both of the following custom builds address this issue, depending on whether you want MonoDevelop or the sexier Xamarin Studio:

https://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/MonoDevelop-3.1.1.dmg

https://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/XamarinStudio-4.0.2442.dmg

Keep in mind that neither of these custom builds have been QA'd. the XamarinStudio link was just sent off to the QA team last night (hot off the press!) for what will become Xamarin Studio 4.0.2 (once any regressions / critical bugs that QA turn up in that build have been fixed).